# Writing CSV file - unable to find solution to avoid duplicating rows given specific condition

Tags: python, csv, parsing

I am attempting to write a new CSV file that parses through a larger file and onle write the rows per my specific conditions.  I am having an issue in getting my conditions to flow properly in that I do not want a new row to be written of the 'SKU number' and 'Part Stocking Flag' is 'Y'.

I attempted to work through this via adding another for loop prior to the main for loop which would continue through the records if the above conidition was met.

Any help is appreciated, below is the code.

```
import csv

with open('4-22 inventory.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)

    with open ('stocking.csv', 'w', newline = '') as new_file:

        fieldnames = ['SEGMENT_CODE','WHS_NUMBER','WHS_GL_NUMBER',  'LINE_CODE',    'SUBLINE_CODE', 'PART_NBR', 'SKU_NUMBER',   'MASTER_ITEM_FLAG',
        'PART_STOCKING_FLAG',   'PART_STATUS_CODE', 'PART_MOVEMENT_CODE',   'SUB_MOVEMENT_CODE',
        'FULL_MOVEMENT_CODE',   'FACTORY_PACK_QTY', 'OH_UNIT_QTY',  'ON_ORDER_UNIT_QTY',    'UNIT_COST']

        csv_writer = csv.DictWriter(new_file, fieldnames = fieldnames)

        csv_writer.writeheader()

        for line in csv_reader:
            for lines in new_file:
                if lines['SKU_NUMBER'] and lines['PART_STOCKING_FLAG'] == 'Y':
                    continue
            if line['WHS_NUMBER'] == 'NCI' and line['PART_STOCKING_FLAG'] == 'Y':
                    csv_writer.writerow(line)
            elif line['WHS_NUMBER'] != 'NCI' and line['SKU_NUMBER'] and line['PART_STOCKING_FLAG'] == 'Y':
                True
                continue
            else:
                csv_writer.writerow(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem in formulating your conditions. The condition:

`if lines['SKU_NUMBER'] and lines['PART_STOCKING_FLAG'] == 'Y':`

**doesn't** check that both `SKU_NUMBER` and `PART_STOCKING_FLAG` should equal to `Y`

**but** it checks that `PART_STOCKING_FLAG` equals to `Y` and `SKU_NUMBER` is logical `True`, i.e isn't empty string, `False`, `None`, etc. So in your case, lines with `PART_STOCKING_FLAG='Y'` and not empty `SKU_NUMBER` will be written.

If you want to check that both `SKU_NUMBER` and  `PART_STOCKING_FLAG` are `Y`, you should do:

```
if lines['SKU_NUMBER']== 'Y' and lines['PART_STOCKING_FLAG'] == 'Y':
    pass
```

Comment: Thank you.  I am actually trying to validate that if the sku already exists (True) and has been written into the CSV with a Part_Stocking_Flag of 'Y', then I do not want to have this row written into the CSV as it will be a duplicate.   My challenge is being able to effectively write this condition so that my loop still parses through without adding skus that have already met the "Y" condition.  Apologies for the confusion.